# When should I use OnPointerClick vs. Input.GetMouseButton?

Tags: unity, mouse

In all games I wrote so far, I used `Input.GetMouseButton` or `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` inside `Update` to detect mouse clicks.

Now I learned that there is another way - I can make my component implement `IPointerClickHandler`, and implement the method `OnPointerClick`.

What is the difference between these two input methods?
 When is it recommended to  use one vs. other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.GetMouseButton` or `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` will just check the raw state of your input (and return a boolean, as it can be only pressed or not pressed)

the `OnPointerClick` callback is working with the Event System of your UI. It gets in parameter a class containing information about the event.

Generally (in UI), you should try to avoid using Raw input in your code.
Using event callbacks, you make sure your code will only be called when the conditions are met (i.e you don't want your code to be called if you are targeting a canvas in front of your object)

Also, the difference between a pointer and a mouse input is that the pointer is "wrapping" the mouse, but also supports touchscreens, graphic tablet, and other pointing devices

Comment: Interesting. So is there no usecase for Input.GetMouseButton?

Comment: it can be used for example for a controller script, but for objects placed as UI, prefer using the event system

Answer (score 0):

[IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) detects clicks on a gameObject with a collider. This makes it very useful when you want to have objects in your scene the player can click on in order to interact with them. Like units in an RTS or buildings in a city builder.

The combination of [Input.GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) and [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) is useful when you want to react to mouse inputs which are not specific to what the player is pointing at but rather how they move the mouse. Like aiming in a first person shooter, moving the camera around a map or implementing drag&drop functionality.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that IPointerClickHandler works on UI objects inside a Canvas by default (which generally don't have colliders, but something like an Image component with raycastTarget enabled), and that you need to add a PhysicsRaycaster attached to the camera to receive OnPointerClick events on non-UI objects with colliders. (I know this is mentioned in the link you shared, I just expect folks to skim instead of clicking through most of the time )